# Material-UI FAB animation between icon and extended variant

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Suppose I have a Material-UI FAB that's code looks like this:

```
  <Fab size="medium" color="primary" aria-label="add">
          <AddIcon />
  </Fab>
```

I have a controlled way to toggle between this other state:

```
     <Fab
      variant="extended"
      size="medium"
      color="primary"
      aria-label="add"
      >
      <NavigationIcon/>
      Extended
    </Fab>
```

My question is how do I achieve some kind of animation between these two states? I'm thinking of a way when the FAB expands, instead of suddenly displaying the text. I can't figure it out, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could be using the Collapse from Transition along with collapsedSize prop

```
    <Fab
      onClick={handleOnClick}
      onMouseEnter={handleHover}
      onMouseLeave={handleLeave}
      variant="extended"
      sx={{ padding: !hoverFab ? 0 : "8px 16px"}}
    >
      <Collapse in={hoverFab} orientation='horizontal' collapsedSize={24} exit={true}>
        <div style={{display: "flex", gap: "8px"}}>
          <div style={{width: 24, height: 24}}>
            AddIcon />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Grow in={hoverFab}>
              <Typography textTransform="initial" noWrap color="#002786">
                Fab text
              </Typography>
            </Grow>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Collapse>
    </Fab>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [MUI Transitions](https://material-ui.com/components/transitions/) for example a `Zoom` animation. So your code becomes:

```
<Zoom
   in={checked} //<-- checked is a bool that you should set to true when this Fab is active
>
   <Fab size="medium" color="primary" aria-label="add">
      <AddIcon />
   </Fab>
</Zoom>
```

And the same thing for the other Fab.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm defenetly up voting it! However, I'm looking for a solution when the text has an 'opening' animation.